# What is the best way to create this list?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am new to Identity 2, and C#.

I want to create a list of email addresses associated to the users that are in current selected role, as referenced by role.RoleId.

I am doing it wrong, I just know it....

so far I have tried

`List<UsersEmailViewModel> EmailList = new List<UsersEmailViewModel>() { new UsersEmailViewModel { Email = ???? } }`

Not sure how to create list entry for each User that is in the Role.

also started to try

`List<UsersEmailViewModel> EmailList = from l in UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == role.RoleId )) select new UsersEmailViewModel { Email = l.email }`

But get an error that it can't convert.

```
if (user.Roles.Count() > 0)
{
    List<IdentityUserRole> userRoles = user.Roles.ToList();

    foreach (var role in userRoles)
    {
        var dbrole = RoleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == role.RoleId);
        if ((UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Admin")) || (UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "SuperAdmin")))
        {
            boundUser.Roles.Add(new RoleViewModel()
            {
                RoleName = dbrole.Name,
                RoleId = role.RoleId,
                //EmailList = Want to create list of only Email Addresses of Accounts in Role

            });
        }
        else
        {
            boundUser.Roles.Add(new RoleViewModel()
            {
                RoleName = dbrole.Name,
                RoleId = "Redacted",
                EmailList = new List<UsersEmailViewModel>() { new UsersEmailViewModel { Email = "Redacted" } }
            });
        }
    }
}

public class RoleViewModel
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<UsersEmailViewModel> EmailList { get; set; }
}

public class UsersEmailViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
var rs = context.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == role).SingleOrDefault().Id; // where role is your role in which you want to find
var users = context.Users.Where(item => item.Roles.Any(x => x.RoleId == rs)).ToList();
foreach (var a in users)
{
    list.Add(a.Email);
}
```